# Is there a Turtlebot package software for iRobot Roomba 600 series base?

Tags: navigation, kinect, roomba, turtlebot, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!!

I'm trying to make my own Turtlebot using a Roomba 645 base, a Kinect sensor and ROS Indigo. I would like to use this platform to make maps (SLAM) using Gmapping package for example.

I've trying to use it with some packages changing the parameters for the roomba base, but the communication fails.
Does Someone has try to use the Turtlebot package for roomba 600 base with success?

Thanks!!!

Greetings

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245156/is-there-a-turtlebot-package-software-for-irobot-roomba-600-series-base?/) by [Diana_Elyza](https://answers.ros.org/users/27895/diana_elyza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2016-10-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can take a look at [AutonomyLab/create_autonomy: ROS driver for iRobot Create 1 and 2.](https://github.com/AutonomyLab/create_autonomy) . According to its [REAME](https://github.com/AutonomyLab/create_autonomy#supported-robots), it may support the 600 series.

---

Originally posted by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) with karma: 1704 on 2016-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Diana_Elyza](https://answers.ros.org/users/27895/diana_elyza/) on 2016-10-06**:
Thank you Mani!!!

I've worked it and it works but I don't know how to use it with the Kinect and the Gmapping package. I'm newbie in this.

Greetings

**Comment by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) on 2016-10-06**:
You are welcome. Now that the base is working, you need to pretty much go through all the tutorials regarding how to setup your custom robot, setting up its kinematic (TF) tree and how to do gmapping/amcl and how to navigate your robot with the ROS navigation stack.

**Comment by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) on 2016-10-06**:
You might be able to re-use many components of the current turtlebot packages, essentially replacing the base driver with `create_autonomy`, update the description files and tweak the launch/configuration files.

**Comment by [Diana_Elyza](https://answers.ros.org/users/27895/diana_elyza/) on 2016-10-06**:
Thank you very much!!!

I'll follow your suggestions.

Greetings =)

**Comment by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) on 2016-10-06**:
You are welcome. It is going to be a rewarding process. Good luck! (PS. If this answer solved your issue, it would be great if you mark it as correct)